# How to call object from Controller to display in the View of ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have one action in my controller :

```
public ActionResult GiftVochure()
{
  if (Request.QueryString["gc"] != "")
  {
    var obj = from b in context.GiftCards
              join cus in context.Customers on b.CustomerID equals cus.ID
              where b.ID == int.Parse(Request.QueryString["gc"])
              select new
              {
                  b.ID,
                  b.Date,
                  b.CardNo,
                  b.Price,
                  CustomerName = cus.FirstName + " " + cus.LastName
              };
      return View(obj.ToList());
  }
  return View();
}
```

And I want to take "obj" to loop and display in the GiftVochure Views, Does any one know, how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by defining a model type to replace the anonymous type projected by the query.

```
public class CardInfo
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    int CardNo { get; set; }
    double Price { get; set; }
    string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Modifying your action method:

```
var obj = from b in context.GiftCards
          join cus in context.Customers on b.CustomerID equals cus.ID
          where b.ID == int.Parse(Request.QueryString["gc"])
          select new CardInfo
          {
              ID = b.ID,
              Date = b.Date,
              CardNo = b.CardNo,
              Price = b.Price,
              CustomerName = cus.FirstName + " " + cus.LastName
          };
return View(obj);
```

Then you should strongly type your GiftVochure view to this type's sequence.

```
@model IEnumerable<CardInfo>
```

In the end you can iterate the items in your view.

```
@foreach(CardInfo current in Model) {
   //display info
}
```

You should probably move your markup for displaying a single object to a partial view. Then render it in your loop.

Comment: I used MVC 2, I can not use "@".

Comment: @socheata I'm sure you can find the syntax for strongly typing your view and a foreach loop in ASP.NET view engine:)

Comment: Ok, but when I did that, It has one error `ModelName does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: Check the first line in your view. It should be strongly typed to `IEnumerable<CardInfo>` , not the CardInfo.